# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[AnyHashable : Any]'

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

when I type like this :

```
func onAppOpenAttribution(_ attributionData: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
    if let data = attributionData {
        if let link = data["link"]{
            print("link:  \(link)")
        }
    }
}
```

I got error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[AnyHashable : Any]'" on this line `if let data = attributionData`

How to repair that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func onAppOpenAttribution(_ attributionData: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
```

your attributionData should be optional type, `if let data = attributionData` if let case is used to safely unwrap an optional value. But currently you are passing a non optional value to it. So you have two options. Either to make `attributionData` as optional, or remove `if let statement`

Option 1:

```
func onAppOpenAttribution(_ attributionData: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
    if let data = attributionData {
        if let link = data["link"]{
            print("link:  \(link)")
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
func onAppOpenAttribution(_ attributionData: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    let data = attributionData 
    if let link = data["link"]{
       print("link:  \(link)")
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: after use ?, the warning still exist

Comment: Parameter of 'onAppOpenAttribution' has different optionality than expected by protocol 'AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate' replace ? with "" after that I got error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[AnyHashable : Any]'" on this line if let data = attributionData again

Comment: Thats a different error. Its something in your code logic. For you current question, i have given the answer. If you have another error, ask a new question instead and we would help you there :)